# How do I add on to this htaccess mod rewrite rule and condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this htaccess rule and condition and it basically says,

> if not position then go ahead and run the rule.

I need it to also say

> if not position or if not occupation then go ahead and run the rule.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!position)[^=]+=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?position=%1 [L,R=301]
```

How can I add where it says `^(?!position)` to also say `^(?!occupation)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alternation like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!position|occupation)[^=]+=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?position=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 conditions with logical or:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!position)[^=]+=(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!occupation)[^=]+=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?position=%1 [L,R=301]
```